# Google Colaboratoryでtensorflowを使おうとしてエラー: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'ConfigProto'

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

まず初めに下記のエラー①がでました。

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat.v2'
```

のエラーがでたので下記を試しました。

```
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.1.0
```

試したら②のエラーはなくなったのですが以下のエラー①が出るようになりました。

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'ConfigProto'
```

どうか解決方法を教えてください。
プログラミングの知識はぜんぜんありません。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

類似の質問がありました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56127592/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-configproto

ConfigProto はバージョン2.0以降では廃止されたようです。
tf.ConfigProto を tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto に置き換えてみてください。

【追記】
変更の一例です。以下のようなコードになっていませんか？

```py
import tensorflow as tf

～～～

## Error
conf = tf.ConfigProto( ... )

## OK
conf = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto( ... )
```

Comment: 大変申し訳ないのですが、無知でしてどのように置き換えるのですか？

Comment: エラーが発生している部分の セルのコードを提供していただいてもよろしいですか。そうすれば、具体的な置き換えてについて説明できると思います。”AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'ConfigProto'”というエラー文の近くにエラーが発生しているプログラムの行番号などが書かれていると思います。